# vc++ - Ftp client code - uploading a file is very slow

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, ftp, logic

I am writing an ftp client to upload file. The pseudo code is something like below

```
{

    command_Socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

    login...//

    pass.. // passive mode

    get the address from the reply ... // 

    data_Socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

    connect the data_Socket to that address ..//

    open the file using createFile(....) //

    loop
    {
        char buf[1000];

        readFile and fill the buf //

        send(dataSocket,buf,..);
    }

}
```

Now, the problem is the uploading speed is 20 kB/s even though I am uploading a file on the same machine . But when a person uploaded one file using ftp, through the lan(His machine was ubuntu), the upload speed was 10MB/s. I can't get the logic behind this.

Note: I am using FileZilla FTP server, it has the ability to show the uploading/arrival speed of client's file .

Answer (score 1):

Posting pseudo code hides probably important performance issues. So it's not clear how do you fill the the variable buf.

But you should not send chunks of 1000 bytes. This can TCP cause to send ACKs more often than necessary at the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudo-code leaves out a few important details, but I'll take a few guesses to compensate :-)

- try making your socket non-blocking, use select() to know when you can write to it and write chunks of just under 64 K
- while your socket is sending (which is asynchronous now) you can read the next chunk of the file

your pseudo-code now becomes:

```
{
   command_Socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    login...//
    pass.. // passive mode
    get the address from the reply ... // 
    data_Socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    /* set data socket to non-blocking  */
    connect the data_Socket to that address ..//
    open the file using createFile(....) //
    /* read a chunk */
    loop
    {
        select
        send data
        readFile and fill the buf //
    }
}
```

making the socket non-blocking allows your code to return as soon as the socket impl. knows what to do, so you don't have to wait around while it does what you need it to do - meaning you can read from the file *while* sending the data.

Comment: Now I put the socket in non-blocking mode,still it is slow .But as for I know blocking/non-blocking can't be considered as asynchronous i/o. Non-blocking means the moment the socket found that there is no further send/recv then finish the send()/recv().

Comment: For writes to a non-blocking socket, the data is copied into the socket's buffers and handled asynchronously from there. For reading from a non-blocking socket you're right: it means it'll simply return if there's nothing to read (i.e. generate a "would block" error). The idea of my suggestion is to make sure your socket impl. always has data to send.

Comment: If just making the socket non-blocking doesn't help, can you tell me where your client code spends it's time? E.g. measure the time it spends in each part of the loop.

Comment: Another thing you could try is de-activating Nagle's algorithm by setting TCP_NODELAY as a socket option. If that helps, it basically means your block sizes are still too small, so you should increase that. When you're done experimenting, Nagle should really be back..

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest using memory-mapped I/O
2. If you want to use `ReadFile` API function, don't read by 1000 bytes.

   2.1 Read 2^k bytes (1024, 2048, 4096, etc...)

   2.2 Read more than 1024 bytes per iteration (for big file it is too small). Try to increase it to 4MB or something like that. You can do this constant file-size dependent.

   2.3 You can use async I/O to read next chunk from file while previous chunk is sending through `send`.

Hmm... may be others can suggest more.

Comment: Are you thinking that ReadFile is slowing down the process?. As for as I am concerning, system calls are the fastest function calls.

Comment: Not actually `ReadFile` but the way you use it: don't read 666 or 1231 bytes. It is really slow. Read 2^k bytes. And for big files, to say 1GB reading by chunks with size 1024 bytes takes 1 048 576 iterations. You should probably increase the size of the buffer.